# why does the p:dialog not submit values to bean

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a small jsf/primefaces application with a datgrid that shows (order) items.
Now I want to add items during a dialog.

1. I open the dialog with a button click. - works
2. I want to submit the values from the dialog to the bean and update the datagrid.
   If I use a default value (not from the dialog) it works. The item get shown in the datagrid and the dialog get closed. That means. 
   -addItem Function works
   -update works

But if I want to add the values from the dialog I get a null Pointer Exception. So my values will not set in the bean.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:fieldset legend="Positionen" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500" styleClass="mbsFieldSet">
        <h:form id="form_positions">

        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" /> 
        <!-- Add position mask -->

        <!-- Button to open the open position mask -->
        <p:commandButton id="btOpenAddPositionMask" value="Position via Dialog" onclick="dlg.show();">
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:dataTable var="banfPosition" value="#{banfPositionBean.lsBanfPositions}"
            id="tableBanfPositions" editable="true" >
            <f:facet name="header">Positionen</f:facet>

            <!-- AJAX Events for editing position values -->
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{banfPositionBean.onEdit}"
                update=":form_positions:messages"/>

            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{banfPositionBean.onCancel}"
                update=":form_positions:tableBanfPositions"  />


            <p:column headerText="Menge" style="width:50px">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{banfPosition.amount}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{banfPosition.amount}" style="width:100%" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Matr. / Lager-Nr." style="width:125px">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{banfPosition.stockNumber}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{banfPosition.stockNumber}" style="width:100%" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Artikel" style="width:125px">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{banfPosition.article}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{banfPosition.article}" style="width:100%" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>


            <p:column headerText="Preis/Einheit" style="width:125px">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{banfPosition.price}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{banfPosition.price}" style="width:100%" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Gesamtpreis" style="width:125px">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{banfPosition.sum}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{banfPosition.sum}" style="width:100%" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Etat-Nr" style="width:125px">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{banfPosition.etat}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{banfPosition.etat}" style="width:100%" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Anlagen-Nr" style="width:125px">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{banfPosition.complex}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{banfPosition.complex}" style="width:100%" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Ändern" style="width:20px; text-align:center">
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Löschen" style="width:20px; text-align:center" >
                <p:commandButton id="deletePos" actionListener="#{banfPositionBean.deletePos(banfPosition)}" 
                 update=":form_positions:tableBanfPositions" ajax="true" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-close" iconPos="center"
                title="Löscht den Eintrag in dieser Zeile." />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>


        </h:form>
    </p:fieldset>

    <p:dialog header="Neue Position hinzufügen" widgetVar="dlg"
        resizable="false">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">

                <h:outputLabel value="Artikel:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="selectArticleForPosition"
                    value="#{banfPositionBean.selectedArticle}" var="art"
                    panelStyle="width:150px" style="width:260px" effect="fade"
                    filterMatchMode="starts" filter="true">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{dataBean.lsArticle}" var="article"
                        itemLabel="#{article.name}" itemValue="#{article}" />
                    <p:column>
                #{art.id} - #{art.name}
            </p:column>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton id="btAddPosition" value="Position einfügen"
                actionListener="#{banfPositionBean.addPos()}"
                update=":form_positions:tableBanfPositions" oncomplete="dlg.hide();"
                ajax="true" process="@all" type="submit">
            </p:commandButton>

    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

I try it with the h:form-Tag as it is shown on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogForm.jsf But If I add this.

```
<p:dialog header="Neue Position hinzufügen" widgetVar="dlg"
        resizable="false">
        <h:form id="form_dialog">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">

                <h:outputLabel value="Artikel:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="selectArticleForPosition"
                    value="#{banfPositionBean.selectedArticle}" var="art"
                    panelStyle="width:150px" style="width:260px" effect="fade"
                    filterMatchMode="starts" filter="true">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{dataBean.lsArticle}" var="article"
                        itemLabel="#{article.name}" itemValue="#{article}" />
                    <p:column>
                #{art.id} - #{art.name}
            </p:column>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton id="btAddPosition" value="Position einfügen"
                actionListener="#{banfPositionBean.addPos()}"
                update=":form_positions:tableBanfPositions" oncomplete="dlg.hide();"
                ajax="true" process="@all" type="submit">
            </p:commandButton>
            </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

the page get reloaded but my bean will not be called either.

Do anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong?
Thanks for help.

**-------------------------------------------**
**EDIT**
**-------------------------------------------**

I try it with an p:inputText instead of an selectOneMenu an the bean gets called.

```
<p:dialog header="Neue Position hinzufügen" widgetVar="dlg"
        resizable="false" appendToBody="true">
        <h:form id="form_dialog">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                <h:outputLabel for="inputTxt" value="Artikel:" />
                <p:inputText id="inputTxt" value="#{banfPositionBean.testStr}"></p:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton id="btAddPosition" value="Position einfügen"
                actionListener="#{banfPositionBean.addPos()}"
                update=":form_positions:tableBanfPositions" oncomplete="dlg.hide();">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

So I just need to find out why it will not work for the selectOneMenu.

Comment: I forget to tell that I tried it with appendToBody="true" for the dialog. `code` <h:form id="form_dialog">
 <p:dialog header="Neue Position hinzufügen" widgetVar="dlg"
  resizable="false" appendToBody="true">..</p:dialog><h:form>`code`

Comment: Do you see any errors in JavaScript console when you use `p:selectOneMenu`?

Comment: No errors in Firebug. Just 2 Posts for updating the part of site: first `<partial-response>
<changes>
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState">-557081259120730458:-2882424255077078609</update>
</changes>
</partial-response>` second `<partial-response>
<changes>
<update id="form_positions:tableBanfPositions">...</update>
<extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"validationFailed":true}</extension>
</changes>
</partial-response>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I don't know what is a type of property `selectedArticle`, I guess it is the same type as `article` (in `itemValue`) attribute. You should define converter or on the other hand you should bind `value` of `selectOneMenu` to be the same type as `article.id`, and set `itemValue` to `#{article.id}`.

Comment: I think your right. I testet it with a Java Object that has no converter. I'll proof it. thx so far.